# Nonlinear ODE eigenvalue problem

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, boundary-value-problem

How does one find eigenvalues $\lambda$ of the following problem?
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 u}{\mathrm{d}x^2} = \lambda \left( -u + u^2 \right),
$$
$$
u(0) = u(1) = 0.
$$
Can this problem be tackled easily by some software? I have looked into Mathematica but its DEigensystem method is unfortunately taylored for the right hand side of the form $\lambda u$ only.

Comment: Maybe substitute to complete a square

Comment: @mathreadler Will that help? I will still have to deal with the absolute term $\lambda/4$ which pops up this way.

Comment: If you complete a square maybe you can do a subsequent substitution.

Comment: @mathreadler If you show me how it can be done to obtain $\mu v$ on the right hand side for some new variables $\mu$, $v$, I will accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A satisfactory answer (to me) appeared on Mathematica StackExchange:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174346/nonlinear-ode-eigenvalue-problem